# How to query for multiple OR'ed Neo4j paths?

Tags: neo4j

Anyone know of a fast way to query multiple paths in Neo4j ?

Lets say I have movie nodes that can have a type that I want to match (this is psuedo-code)

```
MATCH
(m:Movie)<-[:TYPE]-(g:Genre { name:'action' }) 
OR
(m:Movie)<-[:TYPE]-(x:Genre)<-[:G_TYPE*1..3]-(g:Genre { name:'action' }) 

(m)-[:SUBGENRE]->(sg:SubGenre {name: 'comedy'})
OR
(m)-[:SUBGENRE]->(x)<-[:SUB_TYPE*1..3]-(sg:SubGenre {name: 'comedy'})
```

The problem is, the first "m:Movie" nodes to be matched must match one of the paths specified, and the second SubGenre is depenedent on the first match.
I can make a query that works using MATCH and WHERE, but its really slow (30 seconds with a small 20MB dataset).

The problem is, I don't know how to OR match in Neo4j with other OR matches hanging off of the first results.

If I use WHERE, then I have to declare all the nodes used in any of the statements, in the initial MATCH which makes the query slow (since you cannot introduce new nodes in a WHERE)

Anyone know an elegant way to solve this ??  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a variable length path with a minimal length of 0:

```
MATCH
(m:Movie)<-[:TYPE|:SUBGENRE*0..4]-(g) 
WHERE g:Genre and g.name = 'action' OR g:SubGenre and g.name='comedy'
```

For the query to use an index to find your genre / subgenre I recommend a UNION query though.

```
MATCH
(m:Movie)<-[:TYPE*0..4]-(g:Genre { name:'action' }) 
RETURN distinct m
UNION
(m:Movie)-[:SUBGENRE]->(x)<-[:SUB_TYPE*1..3]-(sg:SubGenre {name: 'comedy'})
RETURN distinct m
```

Comment: Sweet, just used a modified version of your query to get results in 250ms ! Thank you ! I love Neo4j !!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [`OPTIONAL MATCH` clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html) might help here. `OPTIONAL MATCH` beavior is similar to the `MATCH` statement, except that instead of an all-or-none pattern matching approach, any elements of the pattern that do not match the pattern specific in the statement are bound to null.

For example, to match on a movie, its genre and a possible sub-genre:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Movie)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g:Genre)<-[:IS_SUBGENRE]-(sub:Genre)
WHERE m.title = "The Matrix"
RETURN m, g, sub
```

This will return the movie node, the genre node and if it exists, the sub-genre. If there is no sub-genre then it will return null for `sub`. You can use variable length paths as you have above as well with `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Comment: Thanks William. I tried using optional match but that was to slow with queries

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

The following `MATCH` clause should be equivalent to your pseudocode. There is also a `USING INDEX` clause that assumes you have first [created an index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-an-index) on `:SubGenre(name)`, for efficiency. (You could use an index on `:Genre(name)` instead, if `Genre` nodes are more numerous than `SubGenre` nodes.)

```
MATCH
  (m:Movie)<-[:TYPE*0..4]-(g:Genre { name:'action' }),
  (m)-[:SUBGENRE]->()<-[:SUB_TYPE*0..3]-(sg:SubGenre { name: 'comedy' })
USING INDEX sg:SubGenre(name)
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/f19x0j) that shows the results for some sample data.

Comment: Your query doesnt include the hard part, I was trying to match the Cypher below if a variable length relationship doesnt exist:  `(m:Movie)<-[:TYPE]-(g:Genre { name:'action' }) `

Comment: Updated my answer to fix a typo. It should now cover that.

Comment: Actually, my original answer already covered that as well, but the updated answer is simpler. The sample data in my linked console contains an example of that.

Comment: Thanks CyberSam ! I appreciate the help . You rock !